# xmlhttprequest POST 405 - Method NOT ALLOWED

Tags: methods, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem that is making me crazy because I'm not able to solve it. I want to upload with my application some files to a server IIS.

My code in HTML is:

```
<input id="files" type="file" />
```

And just in the controller when I detect that a new file is added I use XMLHttpRequest:

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        (xhr.upload || xhr).addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
            var done = e.position || e.loaded
            var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
            console.log('xhr progress: ' + Math.round(done / total * 100) + '%');
        });

        xhr.open('POST', 'http://10.0.19.25:80/CG/files', true);

        xhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            console.log('xhr upload complete', e, this.responseText);
        });

       xhr.send(file);
    });
```

When I launch my app on Chrome, Firefox or IE, I get this error:

```
POST http://10.0.19.25/CG/files 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qs2I.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the problem was that the method what I tried to reach didn't exist, so I tried to use POST but on the server in that URL was expected PUT.

Looking on the server log might probably help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need read more about Content-type. I had the same problem, i was send json data on server and i just change Content-type into application / json; charset = UTF-8, that helped, default is text / html; charset = utf-8.